iPhone does not download & keep original photos from iCloud Photos
I have 1TB empty space on iPhone and 100GB photos and videos on iCloud. Although I have selected the related option to keep originals on iPhone about 2 weeks ago and left the iPhone on Wi-Fi (400Mbps) and charge several nights still, some videos are not ready to play on iPhone without an internet connection. But some, not some but most videos are. And as far as I check all the photos are all fully downloaded.
I watch a video which was previously not downloaded to the iPhone to the end, thus I am making sure the video has been downloaded but then I exit the Photos app, turn the internet connection off and again trying to watch it, it is like as it was never downloaded with an exclamation mark on right bottom corner.
